# Drawing the toric diagram for $\mathcal{L}^{m} \rightarrow T^{2}$ geometries.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

I'm having some problems to understand the geometry involved in the section 3.1 of the paper [Two Dimensional Yang-Mills, Black Holes and Topological Strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406058).

Concretely, I was wondering to know if it is possible to visualize the geometry of the  $X = \mathcal{L}^{-m} \oplus \mathcal{L}^{m} \rightarrow T^{2}$ Calabi-Yau threefold by means of toric diagrams, in other words, how should I draw the image of the moment map of $X$ in *"the physics way"* $(\ast)$.  Here $T^{2}$ is a $2$-torus, $\mathcal{L}^{m}$ is the line bundle characterized by the fact that a holomorphic section of $\mathcal{L}^{m} \rightarrow T^{2}$ has a divisor of degree $m$ on $T^{2}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-m}$ is the inverse bundle of $\mathcal{L}^{m}$.

$(\ast)$ By *"the physics way"* of draw toric diagrams I mean by considering non-compact toric Calabi-Yau manifold $X$ as $T^{2} \times \mathbb{R}$ fibrations over the image of the moment map of $X$ (see [CY 3-folds are $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ fibrations over the base $\mathbb{R}^3$. What does it mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219698/cy-3-folds-are-t2-times-mathbbr-fibrations-over-the-base-mathbbr3)). Below to the left I give the example of the toric diagram of $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ viewed as a $T^{2} \times \mathbb{R}$-fibration over $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{\geq 0}$; $D_{1}$,$D_{2}$ $D_{3}$ are the $2$-dimensional cones of $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{\geq 0}$. This example is discussed in detail in [Topological strings and their physical applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410178) (example 3.1, page 16). Below to the right represents the toric diagram of the cotangent bundle to a $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ embedded on a threefold (see [Branes, Black Holes and Topological Strings on Toric Calabi-Yau Manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512245), section 3, page 8). Here $D_{0},D_{1}$,$D_{2}$ $D_{3}$ are the non-trivial divisors of the geometry where $D_{0}$ is a $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and the remaining $\mathcal{O}(-p) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{1}$ bundles (the relevant $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ are the edges of $\mathbb{P}^{2}$).

[image]

**My problem that I can is that I can't draw the toric diagram of $\mathcal{L}^{-m} \oplus \mathcal{L}^{m} \rightarrow T^{2}$. My faliure goes back to the fact that I have no clue on how to draw a fibration over a codimension 2 cycle ($T^{2}$). I'm unable to draw the toric diagram of $\mathcal{L}^{m} \rightarrow T^{2}$ for example.**

Any hint, comment or reference is welcomed!